# Confused about how to properly use the media object within Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When using [BS3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and patterns/designs that are similar to the [media object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) layout:

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
     <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Does it make more sense to recreate the pattern using BS3 grids (and thus built-in media queries, sorta like [thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails))? For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <a class="col-sm-5 col-md-4" href="#">
    <img src="holder.js/100%x112" alt="media-like-object">
   </a>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7">
    <h4 class="hidden-xs"><a href="#">Media heading</a></h4>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Or is there some way to utilize the built-in media object responsively? I guess I'm confused as the media object seems to be static. What am I missing?

Comment: Your not missing anything. It's meant, AFAIK, to behave just like it does and that's too skinny on nested items. I just use the rows and columns, which is slightly annoying with all the wrappers or just use an ol.

Comment: Here's an example that sizes down smoothly and uses fewer classes markup: http://jsbin.com/neboqa/1

Comment: That's even more confusing to me since you are using `.media-object` on the container, which I guess is a custom class though you are still inheriting the `display:block` from BS. Actually, I think you've created your own media-object, instead of using either the built-in BS media-object or using the built-in grid system. I'm not concerned about nesting (at least just yet).

Comment: It's less confusing to me. But such as it goes